# How to calculate sum of array elements using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Here is what I have.

```
class Array(Subquery):
    template = 'ARRAY(%(subquery)s)'

class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

b_sub = B.objects.filter(a=OuterRef('pk').annotate(items=Count('c').values('items')

result = a.objects.annotate(items=Array(b_sub))
```

And I'm getting

```
# >>> result.first().items
[4, 6, 10]
```

But I need the sum of all `items`(4+6+10)->20 for each `A` row.

Like this

```
# >>> result.first().items
20
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is used for solution

```
class SubqueryCount(Subquery):
    template = '(SELECT count(*) FROM (%(subquery)s) _count)'
    output_field = IntegerField()


sub = C.objects.filter(b__a=OuterRef('pk')).only('pk')
result = a.objects.annotate(count=SubqueryCount(sub))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, understand correct or no your question
but what about sql query, like this:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT SUM(A) FROM UNNEST(MY_COLUMN) AS A) AS TOTAL FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
result = a.objects.annotate(items=Array(b_sub)).aggregate(Sum(items))
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: function sum(bigint[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("items") FROM (SELECT "A"."id" AS Col1, ARRA...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.